# delete from rest store using EXTJS keep deleting previous record again

Tags: extjs4

Below is the code of deleting the records but the first time(after the page reload) deleting a record it has no issue. But when I delete the another record, the store tried to delete it and previous deleted record which cause an error message because the previous doesn't exist.
Don't know how to clear the remove cache or what I should do to prevent the second deletion won't delete the previous record.

```
text: 'Delete',
itemId: 'sa-delete',
disabled: true,
handler: function(b, e) {
    var selected = this.getSelectionModel().selected;
    Ext.Msg.confirm(this._t('Delete User'), this._t('Delete this User'),                    function(button) {
    if (button === 'yes') {
        this.store.remove(selected.items);
        this.store.sync({
        success: function() {
        this.fireEvent('deleted', selected.items);
        },
        scope: this
    });
  }
}, this);
```

Thanks in advance,
Kim

Comment: Normally you use getSelections() not the selected property

Comment: There must be more code involved thats causing this. What does your store definition look like?

Comment: It looks like a bug. As a work around you can try this.store.commitChanges(), to clear-up the changes. 

@mindparse, getSelection() and selected work same. In fact getSelection() internally returns selected.getRange()

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.define('Console.view.admin.USERList',{
    extend: 'Console.lib.BaseGrid',
    alias: 'widget.admin_user_list',
    store: 'USERs',
    requires:['Console.view.admin.USERWindow'],
    cls:'center-panel',
    title:'Users',
    searchable: false,
    columns: [{
        header: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        hideable: false,
        flex: 0.75
    }, {
        header: 'Status',
        dataIndex: 'state',
        hideable: false,
        flex: 0.5
    }],
    enable_item_buttons: function() {
        var tbar = this.dockedItems.items[1];
        tbar.items.each(function(item) {
            if (item.disabled) {
                item.enable();
            }
        });
    },
    disable_item_buttons: function() {

    },
    initComponent: function() {
        this.tbar_cfg = ['->',{
            text: 'Add User',
            scope: this,
            handler: function(b, e) {
                this.load_user();
            }
        },
        {
        text: 'Delete',
            itemId:  'user-delete',
            disabled: true,
            handler: function(b, e) {
                var selection = this.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
                if (selection) { 
                    Ext.Msg.confirm(this._t('Delete User'), this._t('Delete this User'), function(button) {
                        if (button === 'yes') {
                            this.store.remove(selection);
                            this.store.sync({
                                success: function() {
                                    this.fireEvent('deleted', selection);
                                },
                                scope: this
                            });
                        }
                    }, this);
                }

            },
            scope: this
        } , 
        {
            text: 'Generate',
            // save -  selected.items[0].data.name
            itemId: 'user-regenerate',
            disabled: true,
            handler: function(b, e) {
                _this = this;
                var selected = this.getSelectionModel().selected;
                _this.regenerate_user();

            },
            scope: this
        }];
        this.callParent(arguments);
        this.on('render',function(){
            this.store.load();
        }, this);
        this.on('itemdblclick', this.load_user, this);
        this.on('select', this.enable_buttons, this);
    },
    load_user: function(e,row){
        var w = Ext.create('Console.view.admin.USERWindow', {record: row});
        var list = this;
        w.on('saadded', function(data) {
            list.refresh_store();
            if (data.updated) {
               Ext.Msg.alert('Updated User Name', data.name);
            } else {
                Ext.Msg.alert('Registration Id', data.registration_id);
            }

        });
        w.show();
    },

     regenerate_user: function(e, row) {
        var _this = this;

        selected = this.getSelectionModel().selected.items[0].data;
        var values = {id:selected.id, name: selected.name, state:selected.state };
        // var selected = this.getSelectionModel().selected;

        var app = Console.model.USER.create(values);
        // app.proxy = app.proxy +  "&regenerate=1";
        app.proxy.extraParams = {
            regenerate: '1'
        }

        this.store.load();
        var f = this;
        app.save({
            success: function(record, raw) {

                try {
                    var data = raw.response.responseText;
                    data = JSON.parse(data);
                } catch (e) {
                    console.error(r);
                }
                // f.fireEvent("saadded", data);
                Ext.Msg.alert('Registration Id', data.registration_id);

            },
            failure: function() {
                b.enable();
                Ext.Msg.alert('Error', this._t('Unable to re-register USER, try again'));
            }
        });

    },

    enable_buttons: function(selmodel, record) {
        var tbar = this.query('toolbar')[0];
        var del = tbar.query('button[itemId=user-delete]')[0];
        var reg = tbar.query('button[itemId=user-regenerate]')[0];

        del.enable();
        reg.enable();
    }
});
```